# A library for realtime voice changer system in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I was hoping to create a real time voice changer to either run on my computer or from a raspberry pi I own. Basically, I would speak into the microphone and then the sound would be played back in real time with special effects. I've searched stack overflow for a bit and found out how to do a robot voice by editing sine waves but I don't know a library to edit sine waves with. I'm on a windows 64 bit machine.
Thanks

EDIT: The question is, how would I go about editing sine waves from the microphone in realtime?

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a voice changer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959660/how-to-implement-a-voice-changer)

Comment: @Biffen what do you mean?

Comment: @AShelly my question is about making it realtime

Comment: @CiaranWalker I mean there's no actual question here. Just a bunch of statements of what you want to do. What are we supposed to do?

Comment: @Biffen is the edit any better?

Comment: I believe the article in question is a realtime system.

Comment: @AShelly do you have any idea on libraries?

Comment: @CiaranWalker Well, there's a question now, which is better. It is, however, *way* too broad and thus off-topic.

Comment: @Biggen can i have a chance to edit it?

Comment: @CiaranWalker You can [edit] it as much as you like, preferably to make it on-topic. Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Biffen is the title any better?

Comment: @CiaranWalker Nope. Asking for libraries is also off-topic.

Comment: @Biffen any suggestions for a title?

Comment: @CiaranWalker An on-topic title that matches an on-topic question? The title isn't the (only) problem with this question. Do you not understand how it is off-topic?

Comment: @Biffen I'll fix the body after the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[list of audio processing libs](http://en.wikiaudio.org/Audio_programming_algorithms_and_class_library_list)

[Aquilla DSP](http://aquila-dsp.org/)

[DSP filters](https://github.com/vinniefalco/DSPFilters)